# How to Query a query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Using a query to select a `col2` if `col3 = criteria` or select `col3` if `col4` meets the criteria.

I've tried multiple OR statements, tried adding a second query and nothing seems to work for me:

```
= Query(importrange(B7 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col2 Where Col3 = '"&Y116&"'", 0), 
Query(importrange(B7 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col3 Where Col4 = '"&Y116&"'", 0)
```

I want the result of `col3` if the criteria is not matched in `col2`.

Comment: Are you dead set on using Queries for this?

Comment: Use a `FILTER` to apply your criteria. At minimum, provide a sample of data and the desired result.

Comment: I'm not against using a FILTER, just not real familiar with it. I will check into. Thank you for the idea

Comment: I had actually consider doing that, but there maybe up to 8 different spreadsheets that I am pulling data from on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

Google Visualization API Query Language does not allow joins, so you'll necessarily be performing multiple queries. But non-query formulas are sometimes not an option—they do not offer the flexibility and power of queries.

I read your need as:
I need *this* if *that*, [inclusive] or *this other* if *that other*, but all in order.
   A generalized workaround could resemble:
List all the matches for the first select, plus a key column for sorting
Append all the matches for the second select, plus a key column for sorting
Sort the combination list by sorting key
Output just the data column

As a formula, using the row of each WHERE hit as the sorting key:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  SORT({
    QUERY({sourceRange,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(sourceRange))},
      "select Col2, Col5 where Col3 = 'that' ",0);
    QUERY({sourceRange,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(sourceRange))},
      "select Col3, Col5 where Col4 like 'that other' ",0)
  },2,TRUE)
,99999,1)
```

Trying to blow it out for clarity while applying it to your formula:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
    SORT({
        QUERY({
                importrange(B7,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),
                ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(1:700)))
            },
            "select Col2, Col5 where Col3 = '"&Y116&"'",0
        );
        QUERY({
                importrange(B7,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),
                ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(1:700)))
            },
            "select Col3, Col5 where Col4 = '"&Y116&"'",0
        );
    },2,TRUE)
,700,1)
```

Which initially constructs an array of the form:

```
Col2 entry where Col3 matched, row number
Col2 entry where Col3 matched, row number
Col2 entry where Col3 matched, row number
…
Col3 entry where Col4 matched, row number
Col3 entry where Col4 matched, row number
Col3 entry where Col4 matched, row number
…
```

which can then be sorted by the row-number, ascending: `SORT(` … `,2,TRUE)`
and finally cut the keys and print the 700 rows, 1 column of data: `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(` … `,700,1)`

Comment: I am trying to get a part number col2 or col3 based on part name. The spreadsheets containing the required information has been going through some changes, ie: a column has been inserted at the beginning of some of the sheets but not all. My simple select where query has become unreliable because of these changes. I had hoped inserting an OR clause would solve my problems but  I could not get that to work for me. I hope what I'm trying to accomplish is better stated. I appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: You have my pity; that's an awful story. Always better to fix the problem than treat the symptoms though. Insert the missing columns, even if blank. Normalize your sources!

Comment: I only have view rights to the sources, so I am unable to format the sources the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with a `IF`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(index(importrange(B7 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),0,3)=Y116, 
    index(importrange(B7 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),0,2),
    index(importrange(B7 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),0,3)
))
```

- If Col3 = Y116, return Col2,
- else return Col3(You may add a another IF  here to check if Col4=Y116)